# Android ListView and OnClickListener: How to get the selected item

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a listView vith some items.

I would like to get from my onClickListener the name (String) of the selected item.

I know how to get the selected position but how to find the String of this element?

Here is my on click listener:

```
journalNames.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) 
    {

    }});
```

My listView is populated with some query from the database.

Thank you.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What about,

```
journalNames.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) 
    {
      String selectedFromList = (journalNames.getItemAtPosition(position).getString());
    }});
```

Comment: i think the getItemAtPosition()do not return a String

Comment: Amazing, great answer. That's exactly what I needed. Thank you so much. Only add .getString() at the end.

Comment: you can use like this,  String selectedFromList = (String)journalNames.getItemAtPosition(position); or  String selectedFromList = (journalNames.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());

Answer (score 8):

YOu can find it either on view or on parent. In eclipse just type view. and see what methods you get after you type .(dot). I think this is the best.

```
parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
```

Comment: Since your adapter/list may contain more information (e.g. Ids) than are displayed within your list item view, I vote for this answer.

Comment: It must be this way! I always directly accessed list (as a field in class) but I was wrong. Through parent the listener gets encapsulated. Even I had to shift from one list to another, the listener can stay unchanged!